# JQuery - Evaluate TR Class, Delete IMG from matching result

Tags: jquery

Been working on this for a while.

As part of a larger effort, I need to remove images which reside inside a particular TR class.  I have a JSFiddle working (where I mashed up two different approaches I found on SO) but the problem is that the IF statement resolves true for TWO of the THREE TRs in the table but it deletes all of the images.  Even the non-matching one.

I know this is probably very simple.

Two TR Classes:

```
<TR class=rowToClick>
```

and

```
<TR class=hiddenRow>
```

I need the image to be preserved for

```
<TR class=rowToClick>
```

I commented out the very simple JQuery block.  Both produce the same results.

Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/DDjFz/148/

```
// if ($('TR').hasClass('hiddenRow')) {$('td > img').remove();}

$.each(jQuery("TR"),function(){
   if (jQuery(this).hasClass("hiddenRow")) {
       $('td > img').remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$.each(jQuery("TR"),function(){
   if (jQuery(this).hasClass("hiddenRow")) {
       $(this).find('td > img').remove();
    }
});
```

Working demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/DDjFz/149/

Answer (score 0):

Your current selector `'td > img'` will match *all image elements which are direct descendant of all tds* - instead of only those inside the matched `tr`.

Changing

`$('td > img').remove();`

to

`$(this).find('td > img').remove();`

should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

try this one, working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rajesh007/fp9M6/)

```
 $.each(jQuery("TR"),function(){
   if (jQuery(this).hasClass("hiddenRow")) {
     $('td > img',this).remove();
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for looking at my question